# PHP cURL connection timeout in different port

Tags: port, connection-timeout

I'm trying to read shoutcast stream status using curl. the port of stream status normally different from 80. So i'm using CURLOPT_PORT as others answer on this topic .But still getting timed out error.

My code:

```
 $link=trim($_GET['link']);
 preg_match ( '#^http://(.*):(.*)/|;#' , $link,  $matches);
 $ip=$matches[1];
 $port=$matches[2];

 $ch = curl_init();  
 $agent = 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1)';

 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $link);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 100);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $agent);
 curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, $port);

 $contents = curl_exec($ch);
```

example link: `http://206.190.136.212:9402/`
 error: `Failed to connect to 206.190.136.212 port 9402: Connection timed out`

Comment: Hi, I have tested your script and I can say that it's working, no time outs or something like that. The reason why you may get a timeout is that outbound HTTP connections from PHP scripts may be blocked by your hosting provider.